# Why is ReadDirectoryChangesW not triggered correctly when a subdirectory is created inside the watched directory?

Tags: c++, windows, readdirectorychangesw

**(Updated with simpler code)**

I'm using ReadDirectoryChangesW() to watch for changes to certain folders.  It works correctly when a *file* is created in one of the watched folders, but when a *subdirectory* is created it is never notified.

For example, if I watch the path c:\testA\testB and create a file in that folder, then ReadDirectoryChangesW() works correctly.  If I instead create a *directory* in that folder, then WaitForSingleObjectEx doesn't ever return.

Interestingly, if I instead watch c:\testA and create a directory under c:\testA\testB then WaitForSingleObjectEx returns as expected.  Note that I am not watching subfolders, (bWatchSubtree == false) so this result is very strange.

One possible solution is to watch two folders for every folder that I want to monitor, the folder itself for file changes, and the parent folder for any subdirectory changes, but you can see why that is tedious.

Here is some sample code to reproduce the problem:

```
HANDLE watchDir(const char* dirPath)
{
    HANDLE dir = CreateFile(
        dirPath,
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL);

    const size_t kBufferSize = 32 * 1024;
    char buffer[kBufferSize];
    OVERLAPPED overlap;

    memset(&overlap, 0, sizeof(overlap));
    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    overlap.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (ReadDirectoryChangesW(
        dir,
        buffer,
        sizeof(buffer),
        FALSE,  /* bWatchSubtree = false, we only watch one folder*/
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION,
        NULL,
        &overlap,
        NULL) != 0)
    {
        return overlap.hEvent;
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

void main(int nargs, const char* args)
{
    HANDLE watchHandle = watchDir("C:\\testA\\testB");
    if (watchHandle == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Failed to issue watch command" << endl;
        return;
    }

    DWORD result = WaitForSingleObjectEx(watchHandle, INFINITE, false);

    // This code will never be reached when creating a dir in c:\testA\testB, but it WILL if a file is created in that folder.
    cout << "Done waiting for dir: " << result << endl;
}
```

Running this code and making a new **file** at c:\testA\testB\newfile.txt yields this output:

```
c:\testA\testB modified.
```

Running this code and making a new **directory** at c:\testA\testB\newdir is never woken up.

Why does creating a directory cause a notification for two folders up?  Why not just the parent?  Why should creating a file and creating a folder act differently at all?

Comment: Do not lose `buffer`, it tells you what changed.  Right now you have a nasty dangling pointer bug, it writes to a local variable that is not local anymore.  That it going to crash your program in a completely undiagnosable way sooner or later.

Comment: When you create the file or directory, this causes the last-modified time of `c:\testA\testB` to change, which means a directory change is reported for `c:\testA`. (The result of `dir c:\testA` has changed.)

Comment: really `buffer` and `overlap` is wrong used. you got the wrong results. when you create `c:\testA\testB\newdir` - with correct usage - you got 2 notify - (`FILE_ACTION_ADDED`, `testB\newdir`)  and (`FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED`, `testB`)

Comment: @HansPassant This is just the minimum code necessary to reproduce the bug.  In our actual production code, we are of course properly tracking buffer, managing the file handles, etc, etc.

Comment: RbMm I've simplified the code a bit, I don't really care about the results in the new code.  The call to WaitForSingleObjectEx **never wakes up**, so how I interpret the results can't possibly matter.